# USB HID Device connect over RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, usb

I have a USB Scale that is hooked up to my laptop.  I wrote a small application to get the weight from it.  It works great locally, however what I want to is be able to RDP into another server from the laptop where the scale is plugged in and still be able to get the weight.

In the RDP connection settings I have already enabled "Plug and Play devices" however it is still not working.  Is there anything else I should look at in order to try and make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make that happen is to use the RemoteFX feature that is in Windows 7 Ultimate.  Even with RemoteFX, you still may not be able to make it work.  Some HID devices don't work well going through the RDP protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  So currently the scale is hooked up to a Vista machine.  Is there anything similar I can try in Vista?

Comment: Nope, not from Microsoft at-least.  There are some 3rd party tools out there that can perform similar tasks... but they also have similar pros & cons.  Just doing a simple google-search will land you somewhere like this: http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-for-remote-desktop.html

Comment: --That one software package costs about the same as Windows 7 Ultimate Retail.